# Modifying XML using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

How do I modify a value in a XML file using JavaScript/Ajax?

I am able to open the XML file with Ajax, and use it's values in my script, but now I want to send the changes made by my script back to the XML file on the server using Ajax.

It should be possible I think but I can't find an example to learn from. I have followed a lot of tutorials (also from http://lynda.com), but usually they use data from XML and they dont change it.

I prefer not to use other languages because it's a very simple script and XML file, containing only 4 fields.

Comment: Are you trying to modify it on the client side, with Javascript, or on the server side, with some server side programming language?

Comment: the xml file is on a server. i can read it throw ajax and put the values i need in a array with javascript, so that's then on client side. after changing the values in javascript, i want to send the new values to the server. Can i do that with ajax? so i actually need to change the file on the server side.

Comment: yes... see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using javascript you can change the xml values and their attributes of their required nodes.

first you need to get the required node from the xml either by getElementbyname or using javascript xquery.

like example check xml from link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

suppose i have value xml_item = that have that xml.

Like i want to change the value of  tag.
then i do this to change value.
    var element_to = xml.getElementsByName('To')[0];
    //To change its value first detect borwser if it is I.E then use 
    element_to.text = "your new value"
    //if it is not i.e then use.
    element.to.textContent = "your new value";

//if you want to change property value of element you need to do this.
   element_to.setAttribute("attibute_name","new_value");

I hope that you will understand that.

Comment: thanks for reply.. Does this also updates the new values to the server? because you setting new values but dont send them to the server. Thats my problem now... i can change the values, but cant update the xml on the server..

Comment: use javascript function "XMLHttpRequest" to send the xml request to server if that answer help you mark it as corerect answer.thanks

Comment: some thing like this request.open("GET", "files/fruit.xml", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4)
    show(request.responseText.length);
};

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you send xml back to the serverside with javascript:

```
jQuery.post( 
    url, 
    xml_as_string, 
    success( data, textStatus, jqXHR){

    }, 
    "xml"
);
```

You can access the XML in javascript with DOMParser

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/working-with-xml-jquery-and-javascript/

```
// the correct way to use jQuery w/ XML
// also see http://gist.github.com/553364 for a normalized DOMParser

var 
   // XML string
   xmlString = '<wu_tang><member name="Method Man" /></wu_tang>',

   // DOM parsing object
   parser = new DOMParser(),

   // XML DOM object
   xmlObject = parser.parseFromString(xmlString , "text/xml");

// this is WRONG.  It works, but you're not on an XML DOM
$( xmlString ).find("member").attr("name"); // -> Method Man

// the correct way
$( xmlObject ).find("member").attr("name"); // -> Method Man

// in XHR requests the parsing is automatically done for you by
// the browser.  jQuery passes it into the success callback
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'xml',
   url: 'wutang.xml',
   success: function( XMLObject ){

      // OMG
      $( xmlObject ).find("member").attr("name"); // -> Method Man
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. i got this working now like this..         $.ajax({
 type     : "GET",
 url      : "players.xml",
 dataType : "xml",
 success  : function(xmlData){
 
 
 $(xmlData).find("player1").each(function()
 {
   //$("#testing").append($(this).find("name").text());
   var naamTest = $(this).find("name").text();
   $("#testing").html(naamTest);
   
 });
 
 },
 error    : function(){
      alert("Could not retrieve XML file.");
 }
 });     now i want to change the value of naamTest and send it back to xml file on the server... do you have any idea how i have to do that? thanks